# Python: Sort from a particular point

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, numpy, dataframe

```
               Highs
Date
2017-06-01    344.88
2017-06-02    342.88
2017-06-05    348.44
2017-06-06    359.49
2017-06-07    360.50
2017-06-08    371.90
2017-06-09    376.87
2017-06-12    364.50
2017-06-13    376.00
2017-06-14    384.25
2017-06-15    375.46
```

I want to sort these data in such a way,
i have one value ,for example. `2017-06-09    376.87` and i want to start sorting values from that particular value's Index that is, 2017-06-09 in descending order. But i want to restrict the sort function to access or iterate before `2017-06-09` index, i mean, it should'nt sort or access these dates or values

```
2017-06-05    348.44
2017-06-06    359.49
2017-06-07    360.50
2017-06-08    371.90
```

and only sort or access values after `2017-06-09`.

> **Edit 1**

am using,

```
df = web.DataReader('TSLA', 'google', start, end)
Highs = df['High'] # Getting only the values from the 'High' Column

Highest_high = sorted(Highs)[-1]  # returns second highest value
for a, b in enumerate(array):
    if b == highest:
        Highests_index = b
```

The `Highests _index` returns value like 0, 1, 2..instead of dates like 2017-06-01
How can i sort these with having index like 0,1,2..? according to my criteria explained previously above?

> **Edit 2:**

Now i know how to start  sorting from particular index, but theirs 1 more small problem,
if `d = 2017-06-02` we use `df.loc[d:, 'High']= df.loc[d:,'High'].sort_values().values` to sort from that point. but if i want to start sorting by say `d + 5` (2017-06-02 `+` 5) how to do that, so that i could start from `2017-06-09` 5 index away.
as the dates cannot be added.

**Note**: *The Dates(index) are of datetime format.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html), but after sorting `index` values are changed, so need [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) for assign numpy array:

```
print (df.loc['2017-06-09':,'Highs'].sort_values())
Date
2017-06-12    364.50
2017-06-15    375.46
2017-06-13    376.00
2017-06-09    376.87
2017-06-14    384.25
Name: Highs, dtype: float64

df.loc['2017-06-09':, 'Highs']= df.loc['2017-06-09':,'Highs'].sort_values().values
print (df)
             Highs
Date              
2017-06-01  344.88
2017-06-02  342.88
2017-06-05  348.44
2017-06-06  359.49
2017-06-07  360.50
2017-06-08  371.90
2017-06-09  364.50
2017-06-12  375.46
2017-06-13  376.00
2017-06-14  376.87
2017-06-15  384.25
```

EDIT:

For checking second largest index value use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) and then select by `[-2]`:

```
d = df['Highs'].sort_values().index[-2]
print (d)
2017-06-09 00:00:00

df.loc[d:, 'Highs']= df.loc[d:,'Highs'].sort_values().values
print (df)
             Highs
Date              
2017-06-01  344.88
2017-06-02  342.88
2017-06-05  348.44
2017-06-06  359.49
2017-06-07  360.50
2017-06-08  371.90
2017-06-09  364.50
2017-06-12  375.46
2017-06-13  376.00
2017-06-14  376.87
2017-06-15  384.25
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i have edited my questing slightly, Can you please look at the edited question? am trying to get the max value starting from a particular index.

Comment: Awesome plus one sir

Comment: Wow, thats perfect..Thanks a lot bro!

Comment: @BlueQuant - Glad can help!

Comment: @jezrael I have a small problem again, can you please check Edit 2?

Comment: @BlueQuant - I think the best is create new question, is it possible? There the best is add link to this question. Thanks.

Comment: no worries @jezrael, i got the solution for it just now. i just added df.loc[d:, 'High'][5:] and it worked! Thanks for bothering.

Comment: Ok, super. there is not problem with last values? like `d=2017-06-13` ? Then is not possible use d+5, because date does not exist.

Comment: no problem felt uptil now. @jezrael do you know any solution to my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45279174/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-timestamp-and-float  no one answered my question.

Comment: unfortunately not :( it seems some matplotlib problem.

Comment: @jezrael no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

```
df.loc['2017-06-09':,] = df.loc['2017-06-09':,].sort_values(by = 'highs')
```

Comment: That was Quick, let me try it and i'll tell you whether it worked for me.

Comment: bro just add .transform('max')